# Can Delphi Firemonkey TControl.MakeScreenshot work in a thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, delphi, screenshot, firemonkey

I've created a simple FireMonkey screenshot capture that works fine on Android and Windows..:

```
procedure Capture;
var
  B : TBitmap;
begin
  try
    B := Layout1.MakeScreenshot;
    try
      B.SaveToFile( ..somefilepath.png );
    finally
      B.Free;
    end;
  except
    on E:Exception do
      ShowMessage( E.Message );
  end;
end;
```

end;

when I moved it to a thread as below, it works fine in Windows but in Android I get the exception 'bitmap too big' from the call to MakeScreenshot. Are there additional steps needed to employ MakeScreenshot in a thread?

```
procedure ScreenCaptureUsingThread;
begin
   TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
   procedure ()
   var
     B : TBitmap;
   begin
     try
       B := Layout1.MakeScreenshot;
       try
         B.SaveToFile( '...somefilepath.png' );
       finally
         B.Free;
       end;
     except
       on E:Exception do
         TThread.Synchronize( nil,
           procedure ()
           begin
             ShowMessage( E.Message );
           end );
        end).Start;
    end;
```

Later addition. Based on suggestions by Sir Rufo and Sebastian Z, this solved the problem and allowed use of a thread:

```
procedure Capture;
begin
  TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
    procedure ()
    var
      S : string;
      B : TBitmap;
    begin
      try
        // Make a file name and path for the screen shot
        S := '...SomePathAndFilename.png';     
        try
          // Take the screenshot
          TThread.Synchronize( nil,
            procedure ()
            begin
              B := Layout1.MakeScreenshot;
              // Show an animation to indicate success
              SomeAnimation.Start;
            end );

          B.SaveToFile( S );
        finally
          B.Free;
        end;
      except
        on E:Exception do
          begin
          TThread.Synchronize( nil,
            procedure ()
            begin
              ShowMessage( E.Message );
            end );
          end;
      end;
    end).Start;
end;
```

Comment: You should not use *Delphi*, `TThread` and `TBitmap` together in one thought (you will only face bugs) ... and you must access UI controls in the main thread context or you will produce just a random dice application (may work or not)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MakeScreenShot is not thread safe, so you cannot safely use it in a thread. If this works in Windows then I'd say you were just lucky. I'd suggest that you take the screenshot outside of the thread and only use the thread for saving the screenshot to png. Painting should be fast while encoding to png needs a lot more resources. So you should still benefit pretty much from the thread.

Comment: I would be surprised if that works consistently as bitmaps are not thread safe (unless they fixed that recently).

Comment: It is true that you cannot access a Bitmap from two threads at the same time. Here the image is transferred to the thread for saving and nobody else is accessing it then. That doesn't mean that there isn't any bugs that are preventing that (there were some issues in XE5).

Comment: No, you cannot access a FMX bitmap from a thread at all, as it conflicts with housekeeping in the main thread. The only reliable way to access a bitmap is from the main thread. Again, unless they recently rewrote all that (which I doubt and certainly never noticed in the revision lists). It's crazy, I know.